# MongoDB EC2 BenchMark Configuration

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am planning to use MongoDB on EC2 for my web application. Right now I am getting 8000 r/w on MongoDB. My MongoDB instance Type is m1-large.

For the optimum performance I have followed this sites:
[site-1](http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/tag/mongodb/)  [site-2](http://www.colinhowe.co.uk/2011/02/23/mongodb-performance-for-data-bigger-than-memor/)

I have tried a lot but failed to acheive that performace which is mentioned in above site. I want to know is there any other resource from where I can find the optimum EC2 performance Benchmark and some sort of configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you can do to increase write performance on EC2:

**Raid stuff**

Raid 0 will get you better speed but make sure your application
doesn't require the mirroring provided by raid 10 (the recommended
setup)

Rais 10 is mirroring (raid 1) and striping (raid 0) together.

- Note: There's a 2gbs rate limit between an individual EC2 instance and the
  EBS service as a whole, so this is the maximum rate you could ever
  possibly hope to write to EBS from a single node no matter how many
  volumes you have.

**Use sharding**

The more the writes are spread around to different boxen the less
write load each one has.

**Index only the importat stuff**

Try to limit/reduce the amount of indexes you have. With each additional index, an insert or update will also incur additional writes (and therefore worse write performance).

**Control Document size**

Try to control document size so that they don't grow and therefore have to be moved to the end of the collection very often. If you have an array you are pushing to, try to fix (limit) the # of items and their individual size so that mongo can be smart about padding factor and help you out here.

Comment: Thanks Tyler Brock. I have tried this configuration but unabale to get that much output. Can you please tell me how many read and write you are getting per sec. with this configuration?